# how to open the openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i cannot open the openpyxl even though i did as the tutorials said so, I use VSC btw. I'm just a super noobie in python so can anyone guide me? I woould be very thankful.
here is my code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb=xl.load_workbook('transaction.xlsx')
sheet=wb['Sheet1']

cell=sheet.cell(1,1)
print(cell.value)
```

and here is my error:

```
File "/Users/daotronggiabao/Documents/Tài liệu - MacBook Air của dao/python/app2.py", line 2, in <module>
    wb=xl.load_workbook('transaction.xlsx')
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 344, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 95, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1283, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transaction.xlsx'
```

Comment: Put the full path in not just the file name.

Comment: Suggested reading: the section under "You can then either" in the linked thread: